# NavigationBar won't collapse with TabView iOS 15

Tags: swift, swiftui

Not sure if this is a bug, but this is how to reproduce it in iOS 15 (didn't try lower versions)

1. In tab 1, scroll up (navigation bar will collapse properly)
2. Now, tap tab 2, but do not scroll the list
3. go back to tab 1. Now you should see navigation bar failed to collapse.

Source code:

```
struct TestNavigationView: View {
  var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
      TabView {
        LongList()
          .tabItem({Text("Tab 1")})
        LongList()
          .tabItem({Text("Tab 2")})
      }
      .navigationTitle("Navigation Bar Test")
    }
  }
}


struct LongList: View {
  var list = (1..<50).map {$0}

  var body: some View {
    List(list, id: \.self) { item in
      NavigationLink {
        Text("New view")
      } label: {
        Text("Item \(item)")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried to twist the styles, but nothing worked. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `TabView` and `NavigationView` are not good friends with each other.

If you avoid having the `NavigationView` around the `TabView`, you can achieve the same result. Move it to `LongList`, together with the `.navigationTitle()` modifier.

The following works fine:

```
struct TestNavigationView: View {
    var body: some View {
//        NavigationView {
            TabView {
                LongList(text: "One")
                    .tabItem({Text("Tab 1")})
                LongList(text: "Two")
                    .tabItem({Text("Tab 2")})
            }
//        }
    }
}

struct LongList: View {
    var list = (1..<50).map {$0}
    let text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(list, id: \.self) { item in
                NavigationLink {
                    Text("New view")
                } label: {
                    Text("Item \(item) - \(text)")
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Navigation Bar Test")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That would work. However, this way the tab bar would not hide. I was trying to achieve something similar to, say Gmail. When you click an item, it navigates to a new view with tab bar hidden.